# Average in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

```
    Date    Timestamp   μmoles
0   2019-06-11  17:21:35    13.5
1   2019-06-11  17:22:35    13.1
2   2019-06-11  17:23:35    13.0
3   2019-06-11  17:24:35    11.8
4   2019-06-11  17:25:35    11.8
... ... ... ...
394 2019-06-11  23:55:38    0.0
395 2019-06-11  23:56:38    0.0
396 2019-06-11  23:57:38    0.0
397 2019-06-11  23:58:38    0.0
398 2019-06-11  23:59:38    0.0
```

I'm trying to write a code that calculates the average number of µmoles at 5pm. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hi here's an example you can try:

```py
df.loc[df['Timestamp'].dt.hour == 17]['μmoles'].mean() # Follows the 24 hour time format
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are hoping for.

Combine `Date` and `Timestamp` fields into a `date_time` column

```
df["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Timestamp'])
```

Extract the hour into a separate column

```
df["hour"] = df["date_time"].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Print output

```
print(df.groupby(by=["hour"])["μmoles"].mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I'm taking rows which starts with 17: and calculating mean for selected rows only

```
df[df['Timestamp'].str.startswith('17:')]['μmoles'].astype('float64').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
df.loc[df['Timestamp'].str.split(':').str[0] == '17', 'μmoles'].mean()
```